# Where to put the generate keystore in IBM MobileFirst 7.1

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I want to call an external https url from my mobile first java adapter. According to this [tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/01/17/SSL-connection-from-adapters/), it shows the way on how to generate a keystore from a .crt file and put into the mobilefirst security folder. However, I am using MobileFirst 7.1 and cannot find any security folder. May I know where is the /mfp-server/usr/servers/mfp/resources/security folder in MFP 7.1? Or in other word, where should I put the final keystore for MFP 7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default MF uses the uses default.keystore that is in the server/conf directory.
What we have done is insert the required certificates into that that keystore then rebuild the war file.
There is a way to change which keystore to use:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/01/17/SSL-connection-from-adapters/